# How to convert a "TemporalAccessor"-object to a "GregorianCalendar"-object?

Tags: java

I acknowledge that time is a complicated matter, but does it really have to be *that* complicated in Java to convert a `java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor`-object (which I get as result from a `<DateTimeFormatter>.parse(String)`-call) to a `java.util.GregorianCalendar` object (in my local timezone - in case that's relevant here)?

I first tried to compose the path myself, then started to google around and the more variants I find the more I am getting knots in the convolutions of my brain about this! :-(

Do I *really* have to decompose that into a half dozen of fields and then recompose it? This looks absolutely absurd to me. There *must* be an easier way - I hope at least!

Answer (score 3):

## Avoid `TemporalAccessor`

The [`java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAccessor.html) interface is not meant to be used by end-programmers. As the Javadoc says in the first sentence: “Framework-level interface”, meaning this is for internal use by the *java.time* classes and those people implementing alternate [chronologies](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/chrono/Chronology.html). Not intended for us app developers.

## `ZonedDateTime` ↔ `GregorianCalendar`

The terribly flawed [`java.util.GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) class was years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Specifically replaced by [`java.time.ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

You may convert back and forth by calling new conversion methods added to the old class.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;    // Modern class.
Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.from( zdt ) ;  // Converting to legacy class.
```

But do try to **avoid legacy date-time classes** that live outside the `java.time` package. Use `GregorianCalendar` only where required while interoperating with old code not yet updated to *java.time*.

---

By the way, do not confuse [`java.util.GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) with [`javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - very helpful explanation! As background: I was using GregorianCalendar mainly because that's what the XML library I am using generates and expects when converting to/from XML "date" types. 
I will try to switch to ZonedDateTime instead and use GregorianCalendar only during (un)marshaling to/from XML.

Comment: @mmo Do not confuse `java.util.GregorianCalendar` with `javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Instant static Instant.from(TemporalAccessor)
```

And then convert the `Instant` to `GregorianCalendar` via `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: I believe the OP is asking _how_ to do that conversion you say to do "via ZonedDateTime."

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `DateTimeFormatter.parse(String)`, it is mostly for internal use.

Use (using a predefined `DateTimeFormatter` here, but use whatever you need)

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME;
ZonedDateTime result = ZonedDateTime.parse("2023-04-17T11:23:50.6107958+05:00", formatter);
```

If you then really must convert it into a `GregorianCalender` instance (why?) then you can use this additional line:

```
GregorianCalendar gc = GregorianCalendar.from(result);
```